# File handling Code compiles but does not run

Tags: c, file-io

Well what i'm doing is basically i'm reading a file, saving it to an array, and try to print it. But what does seem to be a problem on my code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct{
    int studentNumber;      //struct declaration
    char name[31];
    float quizzes[8];
    float exams[3];
    float overallGrade;
    float standing;
}Student;

//function for transferring

void transfer(Student myList[]){
    int x=0;
    for (x=0; x<3;x++){
        printf("%d\n",myList[x].studentNumber);
        printf("%d\n",myList[x].quizzes);
        printf("%d\n",myList[x].exams);
    }

}
int main(){
    FILE *read = NULL; //creates a stream
    Student myList[50];
    int ctr=0;
    char buf[128];
    read = fopen("file.txt", "r"); //opens the file

    if(read==NULL)
        printf("FILE NOT FOUND!");
    else{
        while(!feof(read)){
            fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), read);  //reads first line
            sscanf(buf, "%d,", myList[0].studentNumber);
            fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), read);  //reads second Line
            sscanf(buf, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &myList[ctr].quizzes[0],&myList[ctr].quizzes[1],&myList[ctr].quizzes[2],&myList[ctr].quizzes[3],&myList[ctr].quizzes[4],&myList[ctr].quizzes[5],&myList[ctr].quizzes[6],&myList[ctr].quizzes[7]);
            fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), read);  //reads third Line
            sscanf(buf, "%d,%d,%d", &myList[ctr].exams[0], &myList[ctr].exams[1],&myList[ctr].exams[2]);
            ctr++;  
        }
    }

    fclose(read);
    transfer(myList);

    return 0;       
}
```

The file consist of three main lines. First is the studentnumber, the second is the quizzes, and the third line is for the exams. The file looks like this:

```
1234567
12,16,14,9,8,15,0,3
40,40,40
1237890
13,12,18,11,7,15,10,8
40,35,50
1232098
10,11,15,10,0,15,6,7
36,42,40
```

Comment: Can you clarify the problems you're having (beyond "it doesn't run") and what you've tried to fix them?

Comment: well basically that's it. As you can see, the code compiles but when i run it, it suddenly crashes. What I'm doing is reading the file line by line by the fgets function, and using the sscanf to save the integer from a an array of struct.

Comment: What's the crash? Is it seg faulting?

Comment: @llawliet_78 just minor problem, line `sscanf(buf, "%d,", myList[0].studentNumber); ` is should be `&myList[ctr]`

Comment: @drum that might be it sir, I'm currently trying to fix my code. But if you have any suggestions as to what's wrong with my code, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @Isaac Thanks for the point out!! Well the code does run now, but the only problem is that it only prints the studentNumber. It does print the quizzes and exams but the problem is it prints a value of 0.000000. I already changed %d to %f  in the printf statement of my void.

Comment: @llawliet_78 then you'd also want `%f` in your `sscanf` bunch.

Comment: @Isaac already tried doing that sir, still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember which old compiler was able to run functions without prototype. But I'll ask you to use:

```
void transfer(Student *);
```

And Also change:

```
void transfer(Student myList[]);
```

To

```
void transfer(Student *myList)
```

Additionally, the First sscanf in while should be:

```
sscanf(buf, "%d,", &myList[ctr].studentNumber);
```

You used 0 instead of ctr.

**Edit:**
Pls don't comment for Problems except the Code or format used.